# How do I create an onReady promise in JS App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects, vuex

There is some Advanced topics in JS I am learning and there is something I am trying to understand.

I've written a VueJS application and I need to expose some data and possibly methods from Vue outside of Vue itself. I am using vuex.

This is so that users can use normal JS on the front end to extend the application.

The idea is the user would add something like this on the front end. I have seen several JS frameworks/apps that do something like this.

`AppName.onReady.then(function(instance) {
    // use the instance object
    var email = instance.data["email"]
    var name = instance.data["name"]
    var isComplete = member.isComplete
})`

Now what I am trying to understand is the code I would need in my App to make the above work.

I know from the code it is a Class AppName that is invoked with new AppName({}) and it has a promise that gets resolved but not sure how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample for returning a promise.

```js
const AppName = {
  onReady() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      // do your stuff here, then call resolve().
      // sample follows
      setTimeout(()=>{resolve()}, 1000)
    })
  }
}
```

Call it like this.  Make sure to invoke `onReady()`, not just `onReady`.

```js
AppName.onReady().then(()=>{
  // your code here.
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this is simpler than I thought I was overthinking it. I did notice though the code gave an error. The Promise needs to be wrapped in another ()
`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`

Comment: Code updated and included a data object to be used inside onReady()

https://jsfiddle.net/6htb1spL/

Comment: I updated the code that was causing the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can can achieve that effect:

```js
class AppName {
  constructor(data = {
    email: null,
    name: null
  }) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  get onReady() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(this);
    });
  }
}

const handleOnReady = instance => {
  const {
    email,
    name
  } = instance.data;

  console.log(`${name}'s email address is: ${email}.`);
};


const tom = {
  email: 'tom@fakemail.com',
  name: 'Tom'
};

const app = new AppName(tom);

app.onReady.then(handleOnReady);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but I have on question. If using 
`...
const app = new AppName(tom);
app.onReady.then(handleOnReady);`

What would the browser support be? Would this only work for browsers that support ES6 classes?

To be clear I am not concerned with the class code as this is inside Vue and compiled to ES5 code on build. But the new envoking of the class would be outside the Vue environment.

Comment: @AndyJamesN - yes that's correct - this code would only work in an ES6 supported environment. If you're concerned about browser compatibility you could use a transpiler such as babel as part of your build process/pipeline to ensure backwards compatibility of newer ES features. https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @AndyJamesN - Just to follow up - I assumed it was fine to write code to ES6 spec since it seems like you plan on having `.then` to handle Promise callbacks - if using ES6 is an issue, you will also have to find a backwards compatible way to handle your callback code.

Comment: Most users that will be writing front end code wont have a build process so I need to keep it simple. I see on caniuse that Promises is not supported at all in IE6 so I may include a polyfill for Promises so it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark a method as `async`.  Then it returns a promise implicitly.

```js
const AppName = {
  async onReady() {
      // do your stuff here, then simply return to resolve.
      // throwing a exception calls reject.
  }
}
```

Usage:

```js
AppName.onReady().then(()=>{
  // app is ready
})
```

If your client is in an async function, you can simply use `await`
Usage:

```js
// must be inside async function
await AppName.onReady()
// app is ready
```

To use `await` at root level, wrap it in immediate executed function:

```js
(async()=>{
   await AppName.onReady()
})()
```